# Python doesn't run the current script

Tags: python

I have this script here (Please ignore the code quality):

```
from datetime import datetime
from bpy.app import handlers

TIMER = None
TOTAL_RENDER_TIMES = []
TOTAL_TIME = 0;
rendertime=None
rendertimeFLOAT=None
def start_timer(scene):
    global TIMER
    TIMER = datetime.now()

def elapsed(dummy):
    rendertime=datetime.now() - TIMER
    rendertimeFLOAT=rendertime.total_seconds()
    TOTAL_RENDER_TIMES.append(rendertimeFLOAT)
    print(TOTAL_RENDER_TIMES)
    #print("Elapsed:", datetime.now() - TIMER)
def complete():
    for x in TOTAL_RENDER_TIMES:
        TOTAL_TIME+=x

    print("TOTAL RENDER TIME: "+TOTAL_TIME)
    print("AVERAGE TIME PER FRAME: "+(TOTAL_TIME/len(TOTAL_RENDER_TIMES)))
handlers.render_pre.append(start_timer)
handlers.render_stats.append(elapsed)
```

It's supposed to get the render time of each frame and return the total time, and average time.
But when I run it, the console tells me this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "\Text", line 14, in elapsed
> NameError: name 'renderTimeFLOAT' is not defined
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "\Text", line 15, in elapsed
> NameError: name 'renderTimeFLOAT' is not defined

My problem, though, is that I *fixed* the error on lines 14 and 15. After some experimentation, I found that the script completely didn't update! It was still running an old version of the script. I have tried saving the text, making a new file, running the script, to no avail. I can go as far as to delete everything in the editor and it will still function.
What's going on!??!
Currently running Blender 3.0 Portable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run the script, it creates a handler and appends it to the list of handlers. When you run the script again, it creates a new handler and appends it, but *the old handler is still there*.

You can check the contents of the handler list in the console, eg.

```
>>> bpy.app.handlers.render_pre
```

It will still have the handler function from all your script runs.

You can clear out the previous handlers by putting something like this at the top of your script

```
# This will clear all handlers (including any you didn't make)
handlers.render_pre.clear()
handlers.render_stats.clear()

# Alternatively, you can try to clear out just the ones
# from your last script run
if handlers.render_pre:
    if handlers.render_pre[-1].__name__ == "start_timer":
        handlers.render_pre.pop()
if handlers.render_stats:
    if handlers.render_stats[-1].__name__ == "elapsed":
        handlers.render_stats.pop()
```